# unity multitouch android 2D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, 2d, multi-touch

I am creating a game and the main character can jump, move left & right. I've got one problem. The multitouch doesn't work. I'm using C# and I've searched everywhere on the internet and I have not found an answer.

my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof (Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class TouchControls : MonoBehaviour {

    // GUI textures
    public GUITexture guiLeft;
    public GUITexture guiRight;
    public GUITexture guiJump;

    // Movement variables
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 50f;
    public float maxJumpVelocity = 2f;

    // Movement flags
    private bool moveLeft, moveRight, doJump = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        // Check to see if the screen is being touched
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            // Get the touch info
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // Did the touch action just begin?
            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                // Are we touching the left arrow?
                if (guiLeft.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Touching Left Control");
                    moveLeft = true;
                }

                // Are we touching the right arrow?
                if (guiRight.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Touching Right Control");
                    moveRight = true;
                }

                // Are we touching the jump button?
                if (guiJump.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Touching Jump Control");
                    doJump = true;
                }
            }

            // Did the touch end?
            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                // Stop all movement
                doJump = moveLeft = moveRight = false;
                rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            }
        }

        // Is the left mouse button down?
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Are we clicking the left arrow?
            if (guiLeft.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touching Left Control");
                moveLeft = true;
            }

            // Are we clicking the right arrow?
            if (guiRight.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touching Right Control");
                moveRight = true;
            }

            // Are we clicking the jump button?
            if (guiJump.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touching Jump Control");
                doJump = true;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            // Stop all movement on left mouse button up
            doJump = moveLeft = moveRight = false;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Set velocity based on our movement flags.
        if (moveLeft)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = -Vector2.right * moveSpeed;
        }

        if (moveRight)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.right * moveSpeed;
        }

        if (doJump)
        {
            // If we have not reached the maximum jump velocity, keep applying force.
            if (rigidbody2D.velocity.y < maxJumpVelocity)
            {
                rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
            } else {
                // Otherwise stop jumping
                doJump = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your script with this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof (Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class TouchControls : MonoBehaviour {

public GUITexture guiLeft;
public GUITexture guiRight;
public GUITexture guiJump;

public float moveSpeed = 5f;
public float jumpForce = 50f;
public float maxJumpVelocity = 2f;

private bool moveLeft, moveRight, doJump = false;

void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch(i);

            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                if (guiLeft.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main)) {
                    Debug.Log("Touching Left Control");
                    moveLeft = true;
                }

                if (guiRight.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main)) {
                    Debug.Log("Touching Right Control");
                    moveRight = true;
                }

                // Are we touching the jump button?
                if (guiJump.HitTest(t.position, Camera.main)) {
                    Debug.Log("Touching Jump Control");
                    doJump = true;
                }
            }

            if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                // Stop all movement
                doJump = moveLeft = moveRight = false;
                rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            }
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        if (guiLeft.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main)) {
            Debug.Log("Touching Left Control");
            moveLeft = true;
        }

        if (guiRight.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main)) {
            Debug.Log("Touching Right Control");
            moveRight = true;
        }

        if (guiJump.HitTest(Input.mousePosition, Camera.main)) {
            Debug.Log("Touching Jump Control");
            doJump = true;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        doJump = moveLeft = moveRight = false;
        rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    if (moveLeft) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = -Vector2.right * moveSpeed;
    }

    if (moveRight) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.right * moveSpeed;
    }

    if (doJump) {
        if (rigidbody2D.velocity.y < maxJumpVelocity) {
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
        } else {
            doJump = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and everything should work. I have tested it with no errors.

Comment: Unity dont see error in the script but in my smartphone, the multitouch doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you sure your smartphone supports multitouch and that the GUITexture is on the right place?

Comment: My smartphone support multitouch ;) I can move my character with one finger, but 2 fingers doesn't work. Wait 5 min, My android SDK has a problem i think

Comment: mmm when Unity make the APK file, i dont see the file.apk and the console say that : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/463093Capture.png

Answer (score 4):

You have to list throughout all touches:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
        Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);
        ..
        ..
}
```

this means, that every touch will be handled separately.
Official documentation [**here**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html).

Good luck with your game.

Comment: it's doesn't work but thx for your answer ... More help please

Comment: Possible syntax error due to only JavaScript example documentation.